# Stanford NLP Parser

Tags: php, nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I have downloaded the Stanford NLP parser zip folder from github. Now I want to run an example. Don't know how to specify path in the given example on github.

example :

```
$pos = new \StanfordNLP\POSTagger(
  '/path/to/stanford-postagger-2014-08-27/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger',
  '/path/to/stanford-postagger-2014-08-27/stanford-postagger.jar'
);
$result = $pos->tag(explode(' ', "What does the fox say?"));
var_dump($result);
```

Also if anyone knows about simple Part Of Speech(POS) tagger in PHP, then please help me.

Comment: Interesting, I'ven't seeen a PHP wrapper for Stanford before, I'll be interested to know if there's one too. For other languages, there's http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/extensions.html

Comment: You need to download and unpack the models from stanford-corenlp-<version>-models.jar to a folder, and then point to this folder.

Comment: Having the same problem here. Do you know how to specify the path?